# How can I change resolution up to 4k if I have a pentium N3540 with a geforce 920m GPU?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I'm a very weird situation.
Looks like the nvidia chipset support the 4k resolution, but the CPU just dosen't.
I have a KD-55A1 televison and I would like to whatch a 4k movie.

All driver is up to date and I don't have missing update in windows 10, and I runed out from ideas.
When I tring to change adapter settings, the Windows drop me to the intel adapter settings, which not to usefull, becouse this intel chipset is uncapable for 4k.
My laptop is a X751MJ, this is a ASUS laptop.
I tryed everything the laptop screen of course turned off, my cable is a dedicated 4k HDMI cable with hdcp 2.2, on NVIDIA control panel set global settings to nvidia chip, there is a wrong way everywhere. I need fresh idias, please help me out.

Comment: Not sure if it's the case with your laptop, but on many older ones with both an iGPU and a dGPU, the dGPU is only a rendering device, and doesn't actually have any video outputs.  If that's the case here, you're limited to your iGPU's resolution limits, because it's what does the the actual video output.

Comment: And how can I find out if that's the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not any easy way to do so reliably.  Unless the NVIDIA settings have options for configuring display resolution while you have the external display plugged in though, it probably is the case.